# Transport SSL must be enabled if security is enabled on a [basic] license

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed Elasticsearch 7.1 on Ubuntu. I want to password protect the cluster, so I have set: `xpack.security.enabled: true` in `elasticsearch.yml` file. Now when I restart Elasticsearch I get the message:

> Transport SSL must be enabled if security is enabled on a [basic]
>   license.  Please set [xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled] to [true]
>   or disable security by setting [xpack.security.enabled]

I am using the basic license. I have seen [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-security) which explains how to use `elasticsearch-certutil` to install SSL certificates on the nodes.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to password protect the cluster without setting `xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled` to true?
2. If I have the guide mentioned above and install SSL certifiactes on elasticsearch cluster, do I need any ssl certificate on my webserver? I don't want the communication between the web server and elasticsearch to use SSL.

Comment: You don't need the SSL certificates on your browser. You can use the http endpoint but you do need to provide username and password for Basic authentication if security is enabled.

Comment: Did you find a solution? and can you post it?

Comment: @MartinAndersen: I wrote down whatever I have learnt in the below answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/setting-xpack-security-enabled-true/182791/7):

> For a cluster that is running in production mode with a production
> license, once security is enabled, transport TLS/SSL must also be
> enabled. On the other hand, if we are running with a trial license,
> then transport TLS/SSL is not obligatory.

---

It's not possible. In production mode, if you want to use any of the xpack security features by enabling  (setting `xpack.security.enabled: true`), then you need to use TLS/SSL certificate.

By default, the web server (and Kibana) can communicate with the cluster without any TLS/SSL certificate (The certificate is used for communication within ES nodes). If you do want to use TLS/SSL between the cluster and your web server, then you need to set `xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled` which is set to false by default.

Comment: I am using docker, so how can I enable basic security?